# When I have to use "accepts_nested_attributes_for"? I need example scenario

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I learned, how to use the accepts_nested_attributes_for. But, I have lot doubts with this.

**What is the purpose?**

**Why it is necessary?** and **When we have to use it?**

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This if from the official Rails Guides:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms